# Send file ( eg. file1.json) to POST REST API , input stream is null

Tags: java, rest, intellij-idea, jersey, jax-rs

I have the following REST API to parse the given JSON:

```
POST
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
@Path("/test")
public String getText(@FormDataParam("file") InputStream fileInputStream, @FormDataParam("file") FormDataContentDisposition fileDetail) throws Exception {
```

when I test it using the chrome extension postman, the filedetail.getName() is working however the input stream received is null. here the post request I sent :

```
POST /parse/test HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8080
Cache-Control: no-cache

----WebKitFormBoundaryE19zNvXGzXaLvS5C
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="1.json"
Content-Type: 


----WebKitFormBoundaryE19zNvXGzXaLvS5C
```

The inputstream received is null .

Note: if I set the content type to "multipart/form-data" I got an exception :

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    com.sun.jersey.multipart.impl.MultiPartReaderClientSide.unquoteMediaTypeParameters(MultiPartReaderClientSide.java:245)
    com.sun.jersey.multipart.impl.MultiPartReaderClientSide.readMultiPart(MultiPartReaderClientSide.java:172)
    com.sun.jersey.multipart.impl.MultiPartReaderServerSide.readMultiPart(MultiPartReaderServerSide.java:80)
    com.sun.jersey.multipart.impl.MultiPartReaderClientSide.readFrom(MultiPartReaderClientSide.java:158)
    com.sun.jersey.multipart.impl.MultiPartReaderClientSide.readFrom(MultiPartReaderClientSide.java:85)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerRequest.getEntity(ContainerRequest.java:490)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerRequest.getEntity(ContainerRequest.java:555)
    com.sun.jersey.multipart.impl.FormDataMultiPartDispatchProvider$FormDataInjectableValuesProvider.getInjectableValues(FormDataMultiPartDispatchProvider.java:122)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$EntityParamInInvoker.getParams(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:153)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$TypeOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:183)
```

so I send it without any header, how can I read the file I sent from the postman, is there anything wrong with my REST API ?

Answer (score 0):

do you use `org.glassfish.jersey.bundle` (jaxrs-ri) ?

if you do, you have to add `MultiPartFeature.class` to your ApplicationConfigure.java (which contains the Override of getClasses())

if you use grizzly so you have to put and register that class in `ResourceConfig`.

here an example for both

first grizzly

```
public static HttpServer startServer() {
    final ResourceConfig rc = new ResourceConfig().packages(true, "your.controllers.package");
    rc.register(MultiPartFeature.class);

    return GrizzlyHttpServerFactory.createHttpServer(URI.create("http://localhost:8080/"),rc);
}
```

now the jersey

```
@Override
public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
    Set<Class<?>> resources = new HashSet<>();
    addResources(resources);
    return resources;
}

private void addResources(Set<Class<?>> resources) {
    resources.add(MultiPartFeature.class);
}
```

I also remove `Consumes` annotation from my method (I believe it detect it as multipart/form-data by default) and also remove content-type from client request because in this case, it cause error 400